# Accessing the Twitter 1.1 API

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth

I've registered my mobile app (Sencha Touch) with Twitter and I have the appropriate keys to access version 1.1 of the API. Now I'm writing a web service to provide the JSON back to my mobile app. Here is what I have so far based on the ruby example provided by Twitter on [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples).

```
require 'oauth'

class Twitter
  def initialize
    @consumer_key = "omitted"
    @consumer_secret = "omitted"
    @access_token = "omitted"
    @access_token_secret = "omitted"
  end

  def pull_tweets(query)
    authorized_token = prepare_access_token(@access_token, @access_token_secret)
    response = authorized_token.request(:get, query)
  end

  private

  def prepare_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@consumer_key, @consumer_secret, { site: "https://api.twitter.com/", scheme: :header })
    token_hash = { oauth_token: oauth_token, oauth_token_secret: oauth_token_secret }
    access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
    return access_token
  end
end

query = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"
response = Twitter.new.pull_tweets(query)
p response
```

When I run this code I get `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>` as a response. After doing some research I found that this could be one of four things.

- My authentication details are wrong
- I'm being rate limited
- Ruby is not formatting the query string properly ([more details](https://gist.github.com/sferik/5208022))
- The query I'm using is wrong

I don't think I'm being rate limited because I've never managed to get a response, and I don't know how to check if I'm authenticating properly. Any help is much appreciated.